# Three js solving black model and turning off bump

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm new to three js or anything 3D so I was following the tutorial for threejs, and I tried to upload my own model in both .glb format, and .gltf format (Exported from blender). Unfortunately, in both cases, the model seems to look something like:
[image: What the model looks like in webpage]

What the original model looks like is:

[image: Original model]

I tried going through the "TroubleShooting" steps in the official Three Js website [https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models]

Following step 2, I tried viewing the model in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com and https://sandbox.babylonjs.com. Turns out, in the first the model renders as intended, but then in the second, the model looks like the black sword in the first image, until I turn of this option called `Bump` in the debug tab in the inspector sidebar. I feel like this is this is how I could prevent my model from going black, but I'm not sure how to do that in ThreeJs.

I know a lot of sites point towards lack of light for the cause of the black rendered models, and so I've played around with different light and all sorts of intensities, such as pointlight, ambientlight, directional, with high intensities, but none of them seemed to work.

Here is a snippet of the relevant parts of my code for reference.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
)

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
// renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
```

```js
const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 1000);
light.position.set(0,0,0);
scene.add(light);

const light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 2, 100);
light.position.set(0,0,25);
scene.add(light);
camera.position.z = 20;
```

```js
let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('/models/sword.glb', gltf => {
    const sword = gltf.scene.children[0];
    sword.rotation.z = Math.PI*.5;
    sword.rotation.y = Math.PI*.5;
    // sword.scale.set(2,1,1);
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
}, undefined, function ( error ) {

    console.error( error );

});
```

Comment: Try to add an environment map to the scene like in this example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/b5c272cf408cb33153190fa715d81581bd95ee47/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html#L51.

Comment: @Mugen87 How do I get the `texture` in that example? Apologies for my lack of knowledge, but I don't have a `.hdr` file that I could load using the RGBE loader anywhere in my project.

Comment: I suggest you take the texture from the linked example. It's part of the official repository.

Comment: @Mugen87 Since I have to activate `modelviewer` as the `environment` option, does this mean that the glb file or the blender file itself is lacking something that should be included before porting it to the web?

Comment: No, since the glb file does not contain any form of environmental lighting.